# Flink filesystem support

Tags: apache-flink

The doc https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/internals/filesystems.html#implementations says "an incomplete list". 
Where can I find a complete one?

Comment: Flink Documentation is bit shaky. Sometimes you got to find out yourselves

Comment: Couldn't look up. Decided to ask before eyeballing the code.

Answer (score 0):

The *Deployment and Operations* section of the documentation includes a page on [File Systems](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/filesystems.html).

Quoting that page:

> Flink directly implements the following file systems:
>
> - **local**: This file system is used when the scheme is “file://”, and it represents the file system of the local machine, including any **NFS**
>     or **SAN** that is mounted into that local file system.
> - **S3**: Flink directly provides file systems to talk to Amazon S3, registered under the scheme “s3://”. There are two alternative
>     implementations, flink-s3-fs-presto and flink-s3-fs-hadoop, based on
>     code from the Presto project and the Hadoop Project. Both
>     implementations are self-contained with no dependency footprint. To
>     use those when using Flink as a library, add the respective maven
>     dependency (org.apache.flink:flink-s3-fs-presto:1.5.0 or
>     org.apache.flink:flink-s3-fs-hadoop:1.5.0). When starting a Flink
>     application from the Flink binaries, copy or move the respective jar
>     file from the opt folder to the lib folder. See AWS setup for details.
> - **MapR FS**: The MapR file system “maprfs://” is automatically available when the MapR libraries are in the classpath.
> - **OpenStack Swift FS**: Flink directly provides a file system to talk to the OpenStack Swift file system, registered under the scheme
>     “swift://”. The implementation flink-swift-fs-hadoop is based on the
>     Hadoop Project but is self-contained with no dependency footprint. To
>     use it when using Flink as a library, add the respective maven
>     dependency (org.apache.flink:flink-swift-fs-hadoop:1.5.0 When starting
>     a Flink application from the Flink binaries, copy or move the
>     respective jar file from the opt folder to the lib folder.

The docs also describe how to implement and register custom file system connectors.